# java array error "array required but int found"

Tags: java, bluej

i keep recieving this error but i dont know whats causing it, could someone please help me understand ?

```
private int [] arrayFeeCode = new int [5];

/**
 * Constructor for objects of class Rally
 */
public Rally(int RC, String Venue, int NumDays, int MaxPlaces, int arrayFeeCode)
{
    // initialise instance variables


    arrayFeeCode[0] = 0.00;
    arrayFeeCode[1] = 10.00;
    arrayFeeCode[2] = 15.50;
    arrayFeeCode[3] = 17.75;
    arrayFeeCode[4] = 20.00;



}
```

Comment: Like @Legend said, your method signature is not right

Comment: actually, remove the `arrayFeeCode` variable from your constructor parameter list. as `arrayFeeCode` is declared as an instance variable you don't need it as an constructor argument.

Comment: Do you really require that in your constructor, it seems to be an instance variable?

Comment: @PermGenError he could have filled that in with an example, not necessarily the defined and constant expression.

Comment: @PermGenError  thanks for your help, i really appreciate it and as instructed ive removed them from the constructor argument and its removed the error

Answer (score 4):

The parameter `arrayFreeCode` is declared as an `int` in your method, yet you treat it as an `int[]`.

Comment: _It's not about the rep - it's about sending a message._ Already been addressed so `-1`.

Comment: That's ok. Just to clarify: was typing this without refreshing the comments. Also, I'd say your comment is more of an answer then a comment :)

Comment: @Legend: there's 1 minute between yours and akalIDIOT's answer, let's stay polite. Answers should be given as answers, not comments.

Comment: @Legend i disagree, unless this isn't a right answer you can't downvote.

Comment: @akaIDIOT im sorry but i do not quite understand your answer

Comment: The last parameter in the constructor for `Rally` is an `int` called `arrayFreeCode`, which your code uses as an `int[]`. You probably meant to use the array in the lines above the constructor, so either change the name of the last parameter of the constructor or remove the parameter altogether.

Answer (score 1):

Are you putting doubles in int array? You need to put ints in it.

Comment: This should be a comment. This is not answer, this is a question.

Comment: @Legend well, he actually made a point here. look at the OP's code he's trying to add doubles into an int array. can you do that ? you can't which makes this more of an answer than a comment :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't put Double into an array of Integer.

Change

```
private int [] arrayFeeCode = new int [5];
```

To

```
private double [] arrayFeeCode = new double [5];
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the parameter `arrayFeeCode`

to

```
public Rally(int RC, String Venue, int NumDays, int MaxPlaces, double[] arrayFeeCode){
     arrayFeeCode[0] = 0.00;
     arrayFeeCode[1] = 10.00;
     arrayFeeCode[2] = 15.50;
     arrayFeeCode[3] = 17.75;
     arrayFeeCode[4] = 20.00;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
private double [] arrayFeeCode = new double [5];
public Rally(int RC, String Venue, int NumDays,int MaxPlaces,double[] arrayFeeCode)
{
    arrayFeeCode[0] = 0.00;
    arrayFeeCode[1] = 10.00;
    arrayFeeCode[2] = 15.50;
    arrayFeeCode[3] = 17.75;
    arrayFeeCode[4] = 20.00;
}
```